# How to find out the size of an object recursively in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, object, memory, size

I have a complex object with properties that range from int, double, string, List of objects, Dictionary<sting, dynamic> ,etc. How can I calculate the size of this object **(without using GC)** ?

I've tried to use reflection, but i was not able to understand it fully, and couldn't implement it.

Example:

```
class Student{
    string name,
    int age
};

class Section{
    int sectionNumber,
    double sectionAverage,
    string sectionName,
    List<Student> students,
    List<string> subjects,
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> studentmapping
}
```

Comment: Define "size", please. Do you mean "memory footprint"?

Comment: yes, the size in memory of the object.

Comment: Then what is the object? The size of the dictionary itself? So for every key the size of its hash and the length of the reference in the value(roughly speaking) and a bit of memory used for managing buckets for hash collisions ? Or do you want also the sizes behind the dynamic in the value? That seems problematic. What if the keys references the same value should it be counted multiple times? Maybe you should rather view the values as not part of a Dictionary they are just referenced by the dictionary. OR rather tells us what this size should be used for.

Comment: What would you want the result to be if a an object could have cyclical references (two objects refer to each other, or a self reference)? Bear in mind you may not know at runtime whether or not that is the case. Do you actually need the size of the whole object graph for a single type?

Comment: @Ralf, for a dictionary, we can consider just the sizes of values and not the keys. if multiple keys reference same values, we would have to count it multiple times.

Comment: @Charlieface, lets assume there wont be any cyclic references. We would have to recursively go though the object's properties till we reach a value type and add it to the total size.

Comment: Dictionaries have cyclical references already, eg in `KeyCollection` and `ValueCollection`. Also how would you *just* count the values and not the keys if this whole process is dynamic? What about the sie of the underlying arrays of references? There is so much here that is not clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this :

```
       public class Student
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }

            public long GetSize()
            {
                return Marshal.SizeOf<Student>() + sizeof(int) + this.name.Length;
            }
        };

        public class Section
        {
            int sectionNumber { get; set; }
            double sectionAverage { get; set; }
            string sectionName { get; set; }
            List<Student> students { get; set; }
            List<string> subjects { get; set; }
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> studentmapping { get; set; }

            public long GetSize(Section section)
            {
                return sizeof(int) + 
                    sizeof(double) + 
                    section.sectionName.Length + 
                    section.students.Sum(x => x.GetSize()) +
                    subjects.Sum(x => Marshal.SizeOf<string>(x)) +
                    studentmapping.Sum(x => Marshal.SizeOf(x) + x.Key.Length + Marshal.SizeOf(x.Value));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the properties here. This class is references in a lot of places, and i want to create a separate helper class, which can fetch the size of any object passed to it